# Facebook: Require someone to 'Like' before they can view fbml tab

Tags: fbml

S O,
I would like to create a separate fbml (tab - with a promotion code) in Facebook that can only be viewed by someone who has Liked the Page. 
Does anyone know how to do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
dresdena1

Answer (score 2):

You may found interesting this page in the FBML docs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/visible-to-connection/

Good luck!

Comment: Glad to her that, your welcome, Mark this as accepted answer.